# DAX code to check multiple selected values in a Treemap

Tags: powerbi, dax

I am working on dynamically changing titles in PowerBI. I have Treemap which displays the population of 6 US states - 2 states from the east (NY, MA) and 3 from the west (CA, OR, WA).

The treemap looks like this -

[image]

A user can choose multiple states from a treemap by pressing ctrl and clicking on the square that represents the state. 
When the user selects both the eastern states, I want the title to say "population in the east states" and similarly for the west too. Can this be done using DAX?

My title requirements -

1. If selected states are MA && NY then display "Population in the East States" as the title.
2. If selected states are CA && OR && WA then display "Population in the West States" as the title.
3. If only 1 state is selected then display the name of the state in the title.

I could do 3. Can someone please help me with 1 and 2?

Comment: How are you doing 3? The title of the visual is static as far as I understand. Are you using a card?

Comment: Yes I am using a card to display the title. I not worried about the Treemap title. I am working on title of the report. The report also has other charts but I want the title to change based on my treemap

Answer (score 2):

Here's a measure that will do this.

```
Title = 
SWITCH( TRUE(),
    CONCATENATEX(VALUES(Table3[State]), Table3[State], ",") = "MA,NY",
    "Population in the East States",
    CONCATENATEX(VALUES(Table3[State]), Table3[State], ",") = "CA,OR,WA",
    "Population in the West States",
    HASONEVALUE(Table3[State]),
    VALUES(Table3[State]),
    "Population by State"
)
```

The `VALUES` function returns a list of the distinct values in the column specified.

Comment: This code will work only when selected in order. (i,e) if I select MA first and NY next, the title changes. If I select NY first and then MA the title remains the same.

Comment: It doesn't matter what order when I test it on my machine, but you can try adding an ordering argument to `CONCATENATEX` (just add `, Table3[State]` after the `","`).